# Can't see files in Ubuntu One web interface, just in android, and in the sync folder

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, sync

I think there is some screen-shots or some documentation missing otherwise, as I've been using U1, for a week or so but I'm not quite sure it is working correctly. This is the thing.

I copied (using XP) my files to the directory that was setup to hold my files synced, but I can't see any file on the web interface of [one.ubuntu.com](https://one.ubuntu.com/). Isn't it supposed to show the filenames that are currently stored?

On the desktop application, it shows 192 MB used, but not a single file is shown online. I'm a newbie at this, that I don't know if I'm getting right the purpose of U1.
Also, I have spent some quality time reading this site, but sometime gets so damn technical, that it certainly discourages any further intent to get it right.

Would like to see some kind of documentation aimed to really newbie users and the screen-shots, really, believe me, can help a lot users in my situation.

Comment: No, it is supposed to store entire file not just filenames, have you synced your Data from XP Ubuntu One client via the sync option. And can you view your files here https://one.ubuntu.com/files/ with the size mentioned.

Comment: Have you looked at the [tutorials on the Ubuntu One FAQ page](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-file-sync/)? It's probably something simple.

Answer (score 1):

I told you... I'm too newbie for this.... 
On my dashboard there are two structures or links with the name of my shared folder (one with tilde ~ at the begining,and other remarked with word "Folders")

The first link gets me to the files, the second just show one level of folders inside that first folder.  I can't figure out what this link is for, since it is incomplete anyway.

The tilde in front of the actual folder containing the files is intimidating... what is it for?

So to abide to the rules for answering my own question, for any newbie that asks for her/his files, go with the folder marked with ***~***, no mater how strange look this for a windows only background people.
Hope not broke any rule posting this, and truly, trying to point the way for a new user in future.